# Using Google Closure Compiler with Play 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, scala, google-closure-compiler

I am reading the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler) for using Google Closure Compiler with Play.

It seems like there is no setup.

I just do `play compile` and it starts compiling any Javascript files in `assets`. However, when I do that, it does nothing. I should have compiler errors because I put bad syntax in one of my Javascript files (just to test this).

Am I missing some setup?